# How to access Laravel symbolic link when uploaded to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm making a laravel webapp and I'm trying to access a image in a storage symbolic link `/storage/images/face-ph.png`.

It works when I do it locally like this:

`<img src="/storage/images/face-ph.png>`

However when I upload it to Heroku it can't find the path.

Comment: php artisan storage:link not working?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I do it localy and it finds the file, but when I upload it to Heroku it doesn't find the file.

Comment: have you tried to run this `php artisan storage:link` on heroku?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz How do you run it on Heroku? I did run it locally in cdm but I don't know how to run it in heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using Heroku for your deployment you can try

```
heroku run bash
php artisan storage:link
```

OR

```
heroku run /app/php/bin/php /app/www/artisan storage:link
```

you can use an absolute path or relative path to run binaries

Hope this helps

Comment: Just tried this. It creates the symlink but there's nothing in it

Comment: make sure your storage folder is not `.gitignore`

Comment: It is not. So now the symlink is there with the image I want. and the route I use is `<img src="/storage/images/face-ph.png">` is that the right path?. Inside my storage folder I have a images folder.

Comment: Which would be the right path to get the image from `public/storage/images/face-ph.png`

Comment: yes  `public/storage/images/face-ph.png` is right path.

Comment: For some reason I don't get the image. It says `404 - not found`

Comment: is it exist in `storage`?

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Comment: The whole storage folder was `.gitignore`

Comment: still having this issue. Any other fix?

Answer (score 6):

Adnan's answer has two issues;

- If you use `heroku run bash` to execute a command, it's only executed in a one-off dyno. So this won't affect the live dyno.
- The `php artisan storage:link` command generates a symlink with an absolute path. So when you'd run this during build, it'd map the absolute path of a temp build directory, instead of the final app's directory on the dyno.

I used a simple relative symlink to link both directories and add it to your git repository:

`cd public/ && ln -s ../storage/app/public storage && cd ..`

Comment: Should I write that in heroku bash? I did, and the same 404 error persists. Also it says that 'storage/public': File exists

Comment: No, your Heroku bash commands are only executed in a one-off dyno, so that won't effect your public app. Simply run that command locally and make sure the changes are committed to your git history before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: @r.vanlaarhoven thanks had been searching for this since yesterday finally this worked.

Comment: @r.vanlaarhoven. you are very smart. It turns out that creating symlinks outside the public folder and inside the public folder really has a big impact. thankyou brother!

Comment: It worked for when id edit the .gitignore to allow the sym link commit. Thank you