# Laravel app stops showing images when transfered to heroku or another computer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

i  need help with my laravel app.
When i transfer the app on another computer or deploy it to heroku,
images aren't showing, while they work just fine on my pc.
Here is the code:

//Index view

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<img src="storage/{{$post->image}}" width="200px" title="">
@endforeach
```

//Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', Post::all());
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts',
            'description' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image',
            'published_at' => ''
        ]);

        $image = $request->image->store('posts');

        Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'image' => $image,
            'published_at' => $request->published_at
        ]);
        session()->flash('success','Post created successfully.');
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }
```

Comment: Permissions? Does the folder exist? Did you run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for the quick response, but that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Laravel symbolic link when uploaded to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849763/how-to-access-laravel-symbolic-link-when-uploaded-to-heroku)

Comment: if you check the page source, is the image URL correct? Can you open it on the browser?

Comment: @Smankusors it does show the correct url, and it shows in browser (on localhost), as soon as i upload it to heroku or transfer it to another pc, images stop showing.

Comment: do you check the url exists if you compared with public folder? Do you have storage link inside public folder?